# Message Body is empty when returning ServiceBusMessage

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a simple .NET 7 dotnet-isolated Azure Function  with Service bus output binding:

```cs
[Function(nameof(abc))]                                                                                                                                            
[ServiceBusOutput("abc", Connection = "abcServiceBusConnection")]                                             
public async Task<ServiceBusMessage> RunDebug([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "POST")] HttpRequestData request)
{                                                                                                                         
    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(request.Body);                                                              
                                                                                                                          
    var requestBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();                                                                
                                                                                                                          
    return await Execute(requestBody);                                                                        
} 

private async Task<ServiceBusMessage> Execute(string input)
{
    // logic...
    var s =  new ServiceBusMessage(                                                   
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(                                                  
        new                                                                       
        {                                                                         
            Id = "abc",                                                      
            Container = "xyz"                                                  
        }))                                                                       
    {                                                                                 
        Subject = "sub1"                                                          
    };                                                                                
                                                                                  
    return s;                                                                         

}
```

The problem is, that Body of each message is empty:

[image]

Why is it like that? Is it possible to return `service bus` message with `subject/label` and returning `string` from azure function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach won't work. To return a message, you can only use primitive types such as `string` or `byte[]`. To return the SDK type `ServiceBusMessage`, you'll need to inject `ServiceBusClient` and create a sender to dispatch your message. Or multiple messages.

See [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1819) for details and the reasons.