# Set label for Service Bus output messages using isolated Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am developing isolated-process azure function in .NET 7. Thats my function:

```cs
        [Function(nameof(ClassName))]
        [ServiceBusOutput("queue1", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        public async Task<string> Run([ServiceBusTrigger("queue2", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] string input)
        {
            return await ExecuteFunctionCore(input);
        }
```

The question is, can i set `subject/label` in scenario like that? I can not use `ServiceBusMessage` class because there is known issue with parsing body https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1819

Answer (score 2):

The issue you referring to has the answer - if you return anything other than a primitive type that could be used as the message body, it will work. The moment you return the `ServiceBusMessage` (SDK type) because you need to customize properties beyond message's body, you need to create a message sender and use it to dispatch the message. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77308981/message-body-is-empty-when-returning-servicebusmessage/77309483#77309483), with further details.