JObject Serialization issues in Azure Functions Isolated process with Service Bus connection
I have Azure Function running on .NET 8 with Isolated process type.
I have Service Bus queue trigger to listen queueA and after processing I want to put message to other queue queueB.
I have code like this:
[Function(nameof(HandleQueueA))]
[ServiceBusOutput(OutputQueueB, Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
public async Task<Envelope<JObject>> Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger(StartQueueA, Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
{
    var eventData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Envelope<JToken>>(message.Body);

    // some logic here

    return eventData;
}

Definition for Envelope class is like:
 public class Envelope<T>
 {
     public string Id { get; set; }

     public DateTimeEpoch CreatedAt { get; set; }

     public string EventInstance { get; set; }
 
     public T Content { get; set; }
 }

In JObject content here I have some business attributed for event itself.
And this works with no errors but at the end in queueB I can see not fully serialized message like:
{
  "Id": "<some-guid>",
  "CreatedAt": {
    "DateTime": "2024-07-30T15:14:38.5585185Z",
    "Epoch": 1722352478
  },
  "EventInstance": "<some-guid>",
  "Content": {
    "attribute1": [],
    "attribute2": [],
    "some-collection1": [
      [
        []
      ],
      [
        []
      ]
    ],
    "collection2": [
      [
        []
      ],
      [
        []
      ]
    ]
  }
}

If I'm trying to serialize eventData before returning from function, I can see correct data
If using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventData):
"{\"Id\":\"<some-guid>\",\"createdAt\":{\"dateTime\":\"2024-07-30T15:40:12.5198266Z\",\"epoch\":1722354012},\"content\":{\"attribute1\":\"attribute1Value\",\"attribute2\":\"attribute2Value\",\"some-collection1\":{\"name\":\"name\",\"value\":\"value\"},\"collection2\":{\"name\":\"name\",\"value\":\"value\"}

I have the next global serialization settings:
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new StringEnumConverter(), new IsoDateTimeConverter() },
};

I would appreviate any ideas what's wrong here :)
Thanks in advance!

ServiceBusReceivedMessage is of type BinaryData and you should use one of its methods to obtain the object.
When the function need to produce a single message as its output, there are two options.

Return body of the message only. In that case, the returning signature of the function would be string or Task<string>, byte[] or Task<byte[]>, or a serializable object.
Use an SDK client to construct and manually send ServiceBusMessage.

See documentation here.

I have no issues with input object obtaining. An issue is in resulting message in output queue. Seems like it's not serialized correctly for some reasons.

Thanks for the clarification. Updates the answer.


I've tried to mark Envelope<T> class with [Serializable] attribute, but it's still serializing only first level of data. Returning directly already serialized string may be an idea, but as last option if no other ways will work.
We it's not an option. We will end up with this still opened bug :( https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1819 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77308981/message-body-is-empty-when-returning-servicebusmessage/77309483#77309483

